# Filter rows based on extracted values and strings in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
    id        area
0    1  139000.00㎡
1    2   52770.00㎡
2    3   undefined
3    4   86540.00㎡
4    5   undefined
5    6  465527.00㎡
6    7    2373.00㎡
7    8   24563.00㎡
8    9  180717.73㎡
9   10  286300.00㎡
10  11   39806.00㎡
11  12   undefined
12  13  285610.00㎡
```

How could I filter rows if `area` which are `>=10000㎡` and `undefined` using Pandas? Thanks.

I have extracted `numbers` from `area` column by:

```
df['new_area'] = df['area'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df = df[~df['new_area'] < 30000]
```

But it raises an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The expected result will like this:

```
    id        area
0    1  139000.00㎡
1    2   52770.00㎡
2    3   undefined
3    4   86540.00㎡
4    5   undefined
5    6  465527.00㎡
6    9  180717.73㎡
7   10  286300.00㎡
8   11   39806.00㎡
9   12   undefined
10  13  285610.00㎡
```

Comment: You need to compare _then_ invert: `df[~(df['new_area'] < 30000)] `

Comment: Does this include `NaN`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column which strips ㎡ and replaces undefined `string` with zero. Convert it to a float.

```
 df['newarea'] = (df.area.str.strip(r'㎡').str.replace('undefined', "0")).astype(float)
```

Boolean select new area equals 0 and new area great than 10000:

```
df[(df.newarea == 0)|(df.newarea >= 10000)]
# df[(df.newarea.eq(0))|(df.newarea.gt(10000))]
```